# Python code help for ArcGIS Field calculator?

Tags: arcpy, python, field-calculator

We are using Python in ArcGIS environment. I want to define a geographical vector data's field as an array and then I want to compare each field's mean average with each other To compute a new C field;

```
If B(average) > A(average) 
 then C = B / A 
else If A(average) > B(average) 
 then C = A / B
```

Example :

Field A: 5, 3, 2, 2
Average of Field A= 3
Field B: 6, 4, 2, 4
Average of Field B= 4

So, Baverage > Aaverage = 4 > 3 then C = B / A Then Field C= 6/5, 4/3, 2/2, 4/2

Answer (score 1):

Use the [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead of Field Calculator, it will give you more flexibility:

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table.

It is unclear what you want to do when mean A = mean B. The code can be executed in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm).

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\database.gdb\feature_class'

fieldlist = ['A','B','C']

a = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'A')]
mean_a = sum(a)/len(a)

b = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'B')]
mean_b = sum(b)/len(b)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if mean_b > mean_a:
            row[2] = row[1]/row[0]
        elif mean_a > mean_b:
            row[2] = row[0]/row[1]
        else:
            row[2] = 99999
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```